# Probability of finding hydrogen atom in its ground state given an initial state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, hydrogen

So I came across this question that asked what is the probability of a hydrogen atom which is prepared in an initial state $\Psi (\vec{r},t)$ to be in the ground state $\psi_{100}(\vec{r}) =2exp(-r)Y_{0,0}(\theta, \phi)$ with $$\Psi (\vec{r},t=0) = 1/\sqrt{2}exp(-r/2)Y_{0,0}(\theta, \phi)$$
where $Y_{0,0}(\theta, \phi) = 1/\sqrt{4\pi}$. 
The answer is apparently found projecting the ground state onto the $\Psi (\vec{r},t=0)$:
$$P = |\int{\psi_{100}^*}\Psi (\vec{r},t=0)dr^{3}|^2$$
What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: This is how you determine the probability of any measurement in QM...

Answer (score 1):

Look for Measurement in quantum mechanics on Wikipedia. There you find that the probability of a measuring a state $|\psi_n\rangle$ with an initial given state $|\psi \rangle$ is given by 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\psi_{n}\right)=|\langle \psi_n | \psi\rangle|^{2} 
\end{align*}
which is in a continuous space (which you have) given by the integral representation: 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\psi_{n}\right)=\int \mathrm d x \, \psi_n^*(x) \psi(x) 
\end{align*}
Maybe this answers your question.